# plesk delete stats and logs - running out of disc space

Tags: apache2, webserver, logging, plesk

My vserver is running out of space. I noticed the traffic stats of apache are taking a lot of space away. I expect email logs, system logs, ... are using some space too.

Is there any way in plesk to delete all statistiks and logs older than a year (or a month)?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logs can be taken care of using the log rotation setting in Plesk. The location of the GUI for it depends on what version of plesk you are using.
v.10
http://www.hosting.com/support/plesk/log-rotation-in-plesk-10

v.9
Domains > domain.tld > Log Manager

As for the traffic retention, again it depends on what version of plesk as to it's location, but in Plesk 10 I have found the easiest way to deal with Traffic Stats retention is via the Service Plans section. (Actually prefer this for the plesk related logs as well, but you can do more with linux's logrotate than with plesk).
Service Plans > [Name of the plan you are editing] > Logs & Statistics tab

Comment: I had plesk pannel v.8. Thx for your hints. Finally updated the whole server which solved the problem.